# Append get parameters to static js files served with node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to append get parameters to static js files served with node + express. The get parameter values will change.

eg -

```
a.com/assets/a.js //should be served as a.com/assets/a.js?v=value
//value will be calculated based on config
```

I need to do this to trigger js cache refresh by the browser.

Comment: I may be understanding the question wrong, but you can append query parameters to any file without any custom code being needed. So you should be able to just include your file as `http://a.com/assets/a.js?v=12.3.4` and it will work the same as including `http://a.com/assets/a.js`

Comment: The thing is I don't want to do it manually for every file.

Comment: By default, express static middleware should have etag turned on which should automatically download if any changes were found on the file.

Comment: yes etag seems more like it.. can you guide me as to how can I enable it only for js files?